# Questions on the first paragraph of Virginia Woolf: “Middlebrow”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence

As far as I understand, didn't Virginia Woolf frown upon the reviewer for posting her address on the newspaper? However, the last sentence seems to express that she thought it is necessary to add the writer's postal address. Could anyone tell me whether she thought it is necessary?

> To The Editor of the “New Statesman”
>
> Sir,
>
> Will you allow me to draw your attention to the fact that in a review
> of a book by me (October ) your reviewer omitted to use the word
> Highbrow? The review, save for that omission, gave me so much pleasure
> that I am driven to ask you, at the risk of appearing unduly
> egotistical, whether your reviewer, a man of obvious intelligence,
> intended to deny my claim to that title? I say “claim,” for surely I
> may claim that title when a great critic, who is also a great
> novelist, a rare and enviable combination, always calls me a highbrow
> when he condescends to notice my work in a great newspaper; and,
> further, always finds space to inform not only myself, who know it
> already, but the whole British Empire, who hang on his words, that I
> live in Bloomsbury? Is your critic unaware of that fact too? Or does
> he, for all his intelligence, maintain that it is unnecessary in
> reviewing a book to add the postal address of the writer?

Source: https://www.falseart.com/virginia-woolf-middlebrow/?continueFlag=3c84aba42763d929cb1985f89b13faf2

Comment: It's sarcasm from beginning to end.

Comment: For the reference to Bloomsbury, (both a district in London - thus a postal address - and the name given to a group of authors) have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloomsbury_Group. Obviously, the critic mentioned this and Ms Woolf made joke of it.